# Importing class in same directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a project named AsyncDownloaderTest with `main.py` and `AsyncDownloader.py` in same directory.I have just started learning python but it seems issue is with the import.

main.py

```
from .AsyncDownloader import AsyncDownloader

ad = AsyncDownloader()
ad.setSourceCSV("https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/grades.csv","First name")
print(ad.printURLs)
```

AsyncDownloader.py

```
import pandas as pd

class AsyncDownloader:

    """Download files asynchronously"""

    __urls = None



    def setSourceCSV(self, source_path, column_name):
        self.source_path = source_path
        self.column_name = column_name
        # TODO Check if path is a valid csv
        # TODO Store the urls found in column in a list
        my_csv = pd.read_csv(source_path, usecols=[column_name], chunksize=10)
        for chunk in my_csv:
            AsyncDownloader.urls += chunk.column_name

    def printURLs(self):
        print(AsyncDownloader.urls)
```

I am getting the following error

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.AsyncDownloader'; '__main__' is not a package`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have `__init__.py` in the same directory as `AsyncDownloader.py`?  That should do it.

`__init__.py` is an empty file that signals that the directory contains packages and makes functions and classes importable from `.py` files in that directory.

You can probably lose the leading `.` in `from .AsyncDownloader` as well.  If you like, you can make the import absolute by changing it to:

```
from enclosing_folder.AsyncDownloader import AsyncDownloader
```

Comment: I created an empty file named `__init__.py` but it didn't work.From my understanding `__init__.py` is for module but here i just want to include a class

Comment: I'm not sure that you can bring in a class or method any other way.  Please see my edits for some additional options.

Comment: Awesome!  Glad to hear it helped.